# Кто автор понятия "вид глагола"?

Tags: аспектология

Известно, что понятие "вид глагола" было впервые применено к славянским языкам. Кто автор этого понятия и в какой работе оно описано?

Comment: https://www.textologia.ru/slovari/lingvisticheskie-terminy/vid-glagola/?n=412&q=486

Comment: Смотрицкий подразделяет глаголы на два вида: первообразный, называемый им совершенным, и производный. В последнем виде он тоже проводит деление — на начинательный и учащательный.


Источник: http://lomonosov.niv.ru/lomonosov/kritika/makeeva-istoriya-grammatiki/razrabotka-kategorii-glagola.htm

Comment: Спасибо. Из текста статьи понял, что в нынешнем виде это понятие определено Бондарко, Буланиным и Масловым. Жаль, что в статье не указаны их работы по этому вопросу, — придется искать.

Comment: Поэтому, если кто-нибудь даст ссылки на их работы, буду признателен.